# Rails app is not taking facebook image after fb login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, facebook-authentication

My rails app has fb login, when the User is authenticated through fb login then i am getting his email and full name but cant able to get his profile pic.

My Application helper,

```
module ApplicationHelper
def avatar_url(user)
    if user.avatar
        user.avatar
    else
            "/images/missing.png"
    end
end
```

end

Omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb is,

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])    

    if @user.persisted?
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
        session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
end

def google_oauth2
@user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Google") if is_navigational_format?
else
  redirect_to root_path, flash: { error: 'Authentication failed!' }
end
```

end

end

my user model is,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2, :facebook]

  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 40}
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.fullname = auth.info.name
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.avatar = auth.info.avatar
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting the authorization from facebook but not getting fb profile pic.

Comment: <li class="round-image-50"><%= image_tag avatar_url(current_user) %></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Looks like you are using **omniauth-facebook** rails gem. In facebook
   auth hash, the image url is available in `auth.info.image_url`. In
   your sample code, you have used `auth.info.avatar`
2. Looks like you are using **Paperclip** gem for storing the image. You
   could look into the following paperclip wiki for downloading a image
   for remote url.
   https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL